# Gesundheit sein v. gesund sein

Tags: sentence-structure, vocabulary

Ich habe im Buch [Sprechen, Schreiben, Mitreden], einen Beispielsatz für Wort Pflegeversicherung gelesen:

> "Die Pflegeversicherung trägt die Kosten, **wenn jemand so schlechter
> Gesundheit ist**, dass es zu Hause gepflegt werden muss."

Der Teil [**wenn jemand so schlechter Gesundheit ist**] kommt mir seltsam vor. Warum benutzt die Autoren nicht (ungesund) als Adjektiv oder (schlechter Gesundheit haben) oder auch ([bei schlechter Gesundheit sein](https://www.dict.cc/?s=bei%20bester%20Gesundheit%20sein))?
Quelle: *Glotz-Kastanis, Jo, and Doris Tippmann. Sprechen, Schreiben, Mitreden: ein Übungsbuch zum Training von Vortrag und Aufsatz in der Oberstufe. Hueber Verlag, 2006.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das ist eine im Deutschen übliche, aber langsam veraltende Form. Mit dem *Genitivus Qualitatis* wird eine Eigenschaft eines Gegenstands oder einer Person ausgedrückt:

- guten Willens sein
- schlechter Gesundheit sein
- schlechter Laune sein
- unverrichteter Dinge heimfahren
  ...

aber auch außerhalb von Prädikativen, wie z.B.

- Wein guter Qualität (sic)
- Waren bester Herkunft
- Pferde edelster Rasse
  ...

Diese Ausdrucksweise zählt (außerhalb von stehenden Ausdrücken) heute eher zur gehobenen Sprache.

Answer (score 0):

Das Adjektiv *gesund* passt hier nicht. Wenn jemand gesund ist, braucht er keine Pflege. Das Wort ungesund passt hier ebenso wenig, denn wenn ich nicht gesund bin, bin ich krank. (Essen mit viel Zucker oder Fett ist dagegen ungesund).

Man kann den Satz ohne Probleme auch mit *bei* formulieren:

> "Die Pflegeversicherung trägt die Kosten, wenn jemand bei so schlechter Gesundheit ist, dass es zu Hause gepflegt werden muss.

Es gibt eine verwandte Konstruktion:

> sich bester Gesundheit erfreuen (*sich etw. (Genitiv) erfreuen*)

Ich, als Muttersprachler, schätze den Satz ohne *bei* nicht als falsch ein, höchstens vielleicht als ungewöhnlich. Ich vermute er kommt aus einer Vermischung des zuletzt genannten Beispiels und der üblichen Formulierung mit *bei*.

Comment: Danke, du hast recht, ich korrigiere es: gesund -> ungesund

Comment: Es wäre wahrscheinlich hilfreich, zu erwähnen, dass „schlechter Gesundheit“ ohne Präposition hier Genitiv ist.

Comment: @CarstenS Echt? so, würde es [jemand der Gesundheit sein] sein? wie kann ich auch andere Struktur bei Genitivform wie oberes Beispiel  erfinden? Können Sie bitte andere Beispiel nennen?